# Sharing on facebook Share Dialog

Tags: swift, facebook-sdk-4.x

I would like to enable users in my app to share certain content on their facebook page such as: url, photo, text. 
This is the only piece of documentation that I could find on facebook website. I can't find any proper tutorial.
Do I need to add any method in App Delegate to configure facebook sdk?

What is the type of `myContent` ?
I don't know where to start.

```
import FacebookShare

let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: myContent) 
shareDialog.mode = .Native 
shareDialog.failsOnInvalidData = true 

shareDialog.completion = { result in    // Handle share results }

try shareDialog.show()
```

> pods spec

```
Installing Bolts (1.9.0)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.38.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.38.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.38.0)
Installing FacebookCore (0.5.0)
Installing FacebookLogin (0.5.0)
Installing FacebookShare (0.5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between `Message Dialog` and `Share Dialog`, the message dialog opens the messenger app with the content, and the share dialog opens the share option in the facebook app, from your code it looks like you are trying to open the share option so you should edit the question title, secondly `myContent` is a type of object that conforms to the `ContentProtocol`, for example like you said sharing a url, you need to create a `LinkShareContent`, here is an example:

```
let linkContent = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")!, quote: nil)

    let shareDialog = ShareDialog(content: linkContent)

    shareDialog.completion = { result in
        // Handle share results
    }

    do {
        try shareDialog.show()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

note: for a photo you can create a `PhotoShareContent`.

Comment: I get error Use of unresolved identifier `LinkShareContent` , Use of unresolved identifier `ShareDialog`

Comment: make sure you have all of these pods: pod 'FacebookCore', pod 'FacebookShare', pod 'FBSDKMessengerShareKit'. clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: And if I want to share url, text and photo in the same post, how do I do that?

Comment: Not quite sure, i haven't dived that deep into this SDK myself, but search for objects that confrom to the `ContentProtocol` and give them a try, maybe the `GraphSharer` not sure. who knows maybe its not even an option :)